# On convergence of series of the generalized mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Assume that $a_n>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ converges.

> **Question:** For what values of $s\in \Bbb R$ does the following series :
>   $$ I_s= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s.$$ converges or diverges?

This question is partially  motivated by some comments [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587408/proving-that-sum-n-1-infty-left-fraca-11-sa-21-s-cdots-a-n1) where it is shown that $I_s$ converges for $s>1$. Moreover, [it is well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357138/if-a-1-a-2-dotsc-a-n0-then-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left-frac-a-11?rq=1) that 
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s = \left(a_1a_2\cdots a_n\right)^{1/n}$$

Accordingly, Taking  $b_n= 1/a_n$ is  one readily get,

$$\lim_{\color{red}{s\to-\infty}}\left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s = \left(a_1a_2\cdots a_n\right)^{1/n}$$ 
it draws from [Carleman's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality) that :

$$\color{red}{ I_{-\infty}}=I_\infty= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_1a_2\cdots a_n\right)^{1/n} \le e  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty .$$
Patently it is also true that the convergence holds for $s=-1$ this is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999/the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-n-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-dotsb-fra).  Whereas the convergence fails for $0<s<1$ 
Indeed, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s \ge  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_1}{n^s}=\infty$$

> **So we have that $I_s$ converges for $1<s\le\infty$ or $s=\in\{-1,-\infty\}$ and diverges for $0<s<1$**.
>
> Hence the original question reduces on studying $I_s$ for $s\le0$ can anyone help?

Clearly the hope is that $I_s$ converges for for $-\infty\le s\le -1 $ and  diverges for $-1<s<0.$`

I don't know if one could infer some conjecture for the case $s=0$ since it seems pathological.

Comment: Hardy's inequality for negative exponents is also known as the Polya-Knopp inequality: just google it. The proofs exploit similar ideas (Holder+induction, or some form of convexity, or Bocharova's approach)

Comment: You might have a look at the *Cauchy-Schwarz and beyond* section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Seriously I feel stupid after your comment. oooo god please step by step. I only know Hardy holder and convexity where do the rest come from?`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Using the [power mean (generalized mean) inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) the convergence for $s<0$ follows easily from the convergence for $s>1$. This probably does not give optimal bounds for $I_s$.

---

It's more natural to set $s=1/t$, so that the integrands are [generalized means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) that, for fixed $(a_n)$, are increasing in $t \in \mathbb R$ by the power mean inequality (which says exactly that). We know that $I_{1/t}$ converges for $0<t<1$ (i.e. $s>1$, by Hardy's inequality, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587408)) and thus for all $-\infty \leq t < 1$ by the comparison test.

We also have that:

- the supremum $S_t=\sup(I_{1/t}/\sum a_n)$ over all sequences is finite for all $t<1$
- $S_t$ is (monotonically) increasing in $t$
- $S_{-\infty}=1$ (take a decreasing sequence)
- $S_{-1}=2$ ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999))
- $S_0 \leq e$ ([Carleman's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality))
- $S_t \leq (1-t)^{-1/t}$ for $0<t<1$ (Hardy's inequality, [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587408))

It's natural to conjecture that $S_t=(1-t)^{-1/t}$ for all $t<1$, which is $1$ at $-\infty$ and $e$ at $0$.

Comment: there is one conclusion in your first statement that I don't understand.  why is this converges for t less than one ?

Comment: I think I have don't what the Op did already check the question again

Comment: this answer is not clear

Comment: @Sobolev I was using a result from a previous question of the OP, see edit.

Comment: @barto  Sorry are you not to just repeating what I have say in the question?n the crucial point is to find the convergence for $ s<0$ which I cannot figure out in your answer

Comment: @GuyFsone $s<0$ iff $t<0$. The answer to your question is in the first paragraph.

Comment: @barto may you elaborate more? in that paragraph you claim the convergence for $0<t<1$ which I did already

Comment: @barto how do you justify your statyement : " and thus for $-\infty<t<1$ " this point is totally not clear

Comment: @GuyFsone by the power mean inequality in the wikipedia link and the [Comparison test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Comparison_Test).

Comment: please I see how obvious the result follows  from comparison test you better read @Jack comments below the question to see that it is not trivial or you write clearly

Comment: See edit; it really is that obvious.